# How to put marker for 10 nearest locations(lat & long value) using on radius based on my current location in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I need to find and mark the locations which are friends in my list, using radius, based on my current location in android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very vague question, but i would advise doing something like this

Create a custom comparator for your the friends list (obviously you will define the methods for getting lat and lngs of friends and the current location)

```
public class FriendDistanceComparator implements Comparator<Friend> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Friend Friend1, Friend Friend2) {

        double distanceBetweenFriend1 = getDistanceBetweenPoints(
                Friend1.getLat(),
                Friend1.getLng();

        double distanceBetweenFriend2 = getDistanceBetweenPoints(
                Friend2.getLat(),
                Friend2.getLng();

        return Double.compare(distanceBetweenFriend1, distanceBetweenFriend2);
    }
}


    public double getDistanceBetweenPoints(Double friendLat, friendLng){

    double currentLat = getCurrentLatitude();
    double currentLng = getCurrentLongitude();

    float[] distance = new float[1];

    Location.distanceBetween(currentLat, currentLng, friendLat, friendLng, distance);

    return distance[0];
}
```

Then where ever you are displaying these friends

```
Collections.sort(friends, new FriendDistanceComparator();

LatLng myLocation = new LatLng(getCurrentLatitude(), getCurrentLongitude());

final LatLngBounds myRadiusArea = LatLngBounds.builder().
            include(SphericalUtil.computeOffset(myLocation, radius, 0)).
            include(SphericalUtil.computeOffset(myLocation, radius, 90)).
            include(SphericalUtil.computeOffset(myLocation, radius, 180)).
            include(SphericalUtil.computeOffset(myLocation, radius, 270)).build();

for (Friend friend : friends) {

    LatLng coordinate = new LatLng(friend.getLat(), friend.getlng());

    if (myRadiusArea.contains(coordinate)){
         googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(coordinate));
    }
}
```

SphericalUtil is added with

```
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3+'
```